# Inserting 1NF Data into Table through a Loop in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, database-design

How do I go about inserting multiple rows into of data into a table to maintain 1NF? Right now I have a html form that creates a group where you can add/invite group members to join. You can add/invite multiple or one: the input of the group members may vary from user to user. I want to take the user input and add it into a table that maintains 1NF. I was thinking of creating a stored procedure in MySQL and call it once I  have the list of values and make 'i' insert calls (i being the number of members a user invites).

My App.route for creating a team: Right now I am inserting data into tb_team table, next I want to populate the team_members table with the users and associated team_id

```
@app.route('/create-team/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_team():
    msg = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Create variables for easy access
        team_name = request.form['team_name']
        invite = request.form['invite']
        team_desc = request.form['content']

    if not team_name:
        msg='Please enter a group name'
        return render_template('create_team.html', msg=msg, team_name=team_name, invite=invite, content=team_desc)

    if not invite:
        msg = 'Please invite users to the team'
        return render_template('create_team.html', msg=msg, team_name=team_name, invite=invite, content=team_desc)

    if not invite and not team_name:
        msg = 'Please fill out the form'
        return render_template('create_team.html', msg=msg)


    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id from tb_user WHERE user_name = %s', (invite,))
    invite_id = cursor.fetchone()
    invite_id_final = invite_id['user_id']

    # Check if team_name exists in tb_team table
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tb_team WHERE team_name = %s', (team_name,))
    name = cursor.fetchone()

    # If team_name currently exists, show error that it is taken
    if name:
        msg = 'This Project Name is already taken!'
        return render_template('create_team.html', msg=msg, team_name=team_name, invite=invite, content=team_desc)
    else:
        msg = 'You have successfully created a team!'
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tb_team (team_name)"
                       " VALUES (%s)", (team_name))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('team_page', group_name=team_name))

return render_template('create_team.html')
```

Here is the design of my database and what I want to ultimately achieve:
[image: Relational design of my database]

with dummy data here:
[image: example populated table data here]

Would writing a stored procedure be the right way about going about inserting those group members?

Passing the list of users to add in a string variable, putting it through a while loop, grab each user delimited by a comma, and add it into the table until no more users exist within the string variable? (See code below on my stored procedure)

```
DELIMITER 
CREATE PROCEDURE basicInsert()
BEGIN
    SET @myArrayOfUsers = '100,102,105,'
WHILE(LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfUsers) > 0) DO
        SET @value = ELT(1, @myArrayOfUsers);
        SET @myArrayOfUsers= SUBSTRING(@myArrayOfUsers, LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfUsers) + 1);
        INSERT INTO `group_member` VALUES(1001, @value);
END WHILE;


END;
 DELIMITER ;


 CALL basicInsert();
```

THANK YOU! All help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question per post. One for the debugging & another for the technique. For code questions give a [mre]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Put everything needed to ask in your post. PS If you don't have too much data you can construct an SQL statement that contains all your strings.

Comment: We can expect this to be a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy, Well, when I had this dilemma I ran across stored procedures which I did state asking if is this how one would normally insert multiple rows into the table given my situation. And I TRIED it. I researched hours on getting the right method for the stored procedure, to use a loop. I would just like if someone validated my thought and process, my method about tackling my problem.

Comment: I told you to compose one query if possible in my 1st comment. (Otherwise, send biggest possible queries repeatedly.) PS It's not clear what exactly you consider to be the clear specific "this" that is your "way of going about inserting" that you have embodied in your code.

Comment: Please don't add data as images only text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: The number of users I have to add varies depending on user input though...

Comment: @nbk Alas see my 1st comment--both [mre] & explicitly re text not images & explicitly tables & ERDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure has some major Problems.

ELT doesn't give back what you wanted. it actually returns the complete @myArrayOfUsers

Debugging LOOP is tricky without temporary tables, but when you are unsure what the result of your code is, remove temporarily the loop add more @ user variables and debug it line for line

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `basicInsert`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `basicInsert`()
BEGIN
    SET @myArrayOfUsers = '100,102,105';
    #SET @myArrayOfUsers = '106,107,108,';
    WHILE(LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfUsers) > 0) DO
            SET @value = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@myArrayOfUsers,',',1);
            IF (LENGTH(@myArrayOfUsers) > LENGTH(@value) +2)  THEN
                SET @myArrayOfUsers= SUBSTRING(@myArrayOfUsers, LENGTH(@value) + 2);
                INSERT INTO `group_member` VALUES(1001, @value);
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO `group_member` VALUES(1001, @value);
                -- to end while loop
                SET @myArrayOfUsers=  '';
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(@myArrayOfUsers) > 0 AND LOCATE(',', @myArrayOfUsers) = 0 then
                -- Last entry was withóut comma
                INSERT INTO `group_member` VALUES(1001, @myArrayOfUsers);
            END IF;
    END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I test as you can see also teh case when no comma is at the end.

As you only want to do !NF, i don't check for already existing entrys

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I will be sure to troubleshoot and debug loops well in my next set of features. Cheers!  I'm fairly new in implementing stored procedures and this gave me great insight @nbk